# Printing the values of multidimensional arrays

Tags: arrays, c, function, multidimensional-array

> Greetings of the day

I am a beginner to C.

I am learning C.

I am solving a problem of 2d array.

The problem is I have to take values of multidimensional array and print them.

And the way of printing should be like this :

```
2 3
4 5
6 7

/*
Array is like-
{
{2,3},
{4,5},
{6,7}
}
*/
```

So I think The Problem is cleared to you.

My Code is giving me a lot of errors

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int ptr[] ,int n,int nt);

int main(){
    
    int arr[3][2];
    
    
    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<2 ; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    
    
    display(arr,3,2);

    return 0;
}


void display(int ptr[],int n,int nt){
        
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<nt ; j++){
            printf("%d", ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

**My Errors**

```
/storage/emulated/0/C/Practice/Arrays/multidimensional arrays/quick_quic.c:19:10: warning: 
      incompatible pointer types passing 'int [3][3]'
      to parameter of type 'int *'
      [-Wincompatible-pointer-types]
        display(arr,3,3);
                ^~~
/storage/emulated/0/C/Practice/Arrays/multidimensional arrays/quick_quic.c:4:18: note: 
      passing argument to parameter 'ptr' here
void display(int ptr[] ,int n,int nt);
                 ^
/storage/emulated/0/C/Practice/Arrays/multidimensional arrays/quick_quic.c:29:23: error: 
      subscripted value is not an array, pointer, or
      vector
                        printf("%d", ptr[i][j]);
                                     ~~~~~~^~
1 warning and 1 error generated.
```

Comment: "My Code is giving me a lot of errors" Which? Please quote them here, in full, as text, verbatim.

Comment: You show calues of a 2x3 array and code a 3x3 array. Is there a reason for that difference?

Comment: I have edited the Question with errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a complete beginners which I am considering you're to pass the multidimensional array you need to mention the bound in the argument aswell.

Note:- Inner bound is not necessary but outer bound is!

In the above case

```
void display(int ptr[][3] ,int n,int nt);
```

And same while defining the function
That's

```
void display(int ptr[][3],int n,int nt){
    
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<nt ; j++){
            printf("%d", ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

So the correct program for above would be

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int ptr[][3],int n,int nt);

int main(){

    int arr[3][3];


    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }

    display(arr,3,3);

    return 0;
}


void display(int ptr[][3],int n,int nt){
    
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<nt ; j++){
            printf("%d", ptr[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Also you can always use pointer or call by reference if you study further you'll study that aswell!

Edit:

Using pointers

```
#include <stdio.h>

void display(int *ptr,int n,int nt);

int main(){
 
    int arr[3][3];
    for(int i=0 ; i<3 ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<3 ; j++){
            scanf("%d", &arr[i][j]);
        }
    }
    //passing the pointer to first element
    display(&arr[0][0],3,3);
    return 0;
}


void display(int *ptr,int n,int nt){        
    for(int i=0 ; i<n ; i++){
        for(int j=0 ; j<nt ; j++){
            printf("%d",*((ptr+i*n)+j));
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}
```

Check More about [Pointer To Array Here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/pointer-array-array-pointer)

Comment: Thanks You Very Much For A Such Crystal Clear Understanding .  Can you please edit the pointer approach also

Comment: Hey , can I ask a help from you.

Answer (score 0):

The type of `arr` (`int [3][3]`) doesn't match `ptr` (`int []`).  To make this work, you will either have to change the type of `ptr`:

```
void display( int ptr[][3], int n, int nt )
{
  ...
}
```

or you will need to pretend `arr` is a 1D array - you can do that by passing the address of the first element explicitly:

```
display( &arr[0][0], 3, 3 );
```

and then in `display` use a single subscript:

```
printf( "%d", ptr[i * n + j] );
```

Comment: It is going more harder for me. . I can't understand